# Copy image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to copy an image and rename in the same directory using Javascript.
I have search it for days just this code

```
 object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

but it just run on IE. I want the code run on Chrome and Firefox. Any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Copy how? Copy to clipboard? Copy to filesystem? Clone the image into another element?

Comment: javascript is a client side scripting language, you can't do server side actions using javascript. you gonna need a server side JavaScript runtime environments like Node.js for these kind of things.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I want to duplicate an image in a folder with different name.
like in php copy($srcfile, $dstfile);

Comment: @EmadDehnavi Is it impossible using javascript?

Comment: @rpangab Yes, It is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it can't be done. Or well, you can use e.g. the Chrome FileSystem API, but you can't get a cross browser solution for this.

If you want to do something like this in Javascript I suggest you move to creating a Node.js server application using Express, it seems like the best choice for you.

And for gods sake, stop developing for Internet Explorer! IE is something you add support for in case you have the extra time for it, it's not something you target primarily!